# Core data Background slow and background save, sqlite background and mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, background-process

I'm writing an update for my app, i need to insert inside the db 30 images. Now i'm using core data, and it saves correctly but it takes 10 seconds... So i have decided to send in background the saving process. I have a for cycle that works the image array, each turn i create an NSmanagedObject and i save it. With this base i have try different solution, nothing works correctly:

1-----------------------

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Add code here to do background processing
    //context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObjectContext *contextTemp = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *store=[(RecipesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator];
    contextTemp.persistentStoreCoordinator=store;

    Recipe *recipe = (Recipe *)[contextTemp objectWithID:MoID];


    NSManagedObject *image = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:contextTemp];
    [image setValue:[[ArrayDizionariImmagini objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"image"] forKey:@"image"];
    [image setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"data"];

    recipe.image=image;
    [contextTemp save:nil];


});
```

This method saves all in the correct way but it takes 10 seconds,just like my first attemp in mainthread,so it's useless...

2-----------------------------------------------------

```
dispatch_queue_t request_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.doeatraw.saveimages", NULL);
dispatch_async(request_queue, ^{

    // Create a new managed object context
    // Set its persistent store coordinator
    AppDelegate *theDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *newMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [newMoc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[theDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    // Register for context save changes notification
    NSNotificationCenter *notify = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notify addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                   name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                 object:newMoc];


    BOOL success = [newMoc save:nil];

});
dispatch_release(request_queue);

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    context = [(RecipesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    [context performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

In this attemp i save a temporary ManagedObjectContext only at the end of all the update and then i try to merge changes. In this way i can save all the images in background an i my UI remain responsive all the time. But if i close and i reopen the app all my savings are losts...so it became clear that core data didn't any real merge.

3------------------------------------------------------------

I have also try to direct insert all the data by sql. I have put all in background and it seems ok, ui is responsive and all data are inserted...Anyway something go wrong. When i try to access the same table (by launching other indipendent methods in the app that interrogates the same table) sql crash the app without error in log(only one time i have received the error "Constraint Failed"). I'm able to extract and visualize the inserted images but i cant mad another insert (by core data) in the table.

Someone can help me? I know that NSManagedObjectContext isn't thread safe, but i have tried to follow the documentation guidelines in some of my attemps...Maybe i miss something...
What i'm trying to save is an nsmanagedobject with the image as relationship. How i can real merge my contexts? Or what i can do with the error sqlite Constraint Failed?

Comment: In that last bit, it sounds like maybe you're trying to use SQLite directly against your Core Data database? That's a big no-no. Don't try that. The persistent store should only be manipulated by the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. It will break. See Valentin's answer below - consider not saving large binary objects in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your overhead comes from creating a new context each time you save an image. That's an expensive operation. You only need 2 contexts, one for the main queue and the second for a serial background queue. Also, please note that Apple advises against storing images in the database, the experience I have says the same thing. You should only keep the image path in the database, and keep the image on the file system.

Comment: i have tried to create one new managedobjectcontext and then loop all the images. Each image will set inside the new context as managedobject and only at the end of the for cicle i save the new context and i merge it with the context of the appdelegate. Record are saved correctly and the method is excecuted in background but the merge operation block the UI and this isn't good

Comment: Actually, creating a MOC is not a very expensive operation at all... It's what you do with it that can sometimes cause you trouble (i.e. saving a large amount of data). Saving images in the DB, depending on the size, can cause exactly the type of problems you're encountering. As Valentin mentioned, consider saving the images in the file system and pointers to those files in Core Data. Often much faster.

Comment: True, but still an overhead since it can be avoided. Taking this a step further, probably it's more like a design flaw than an actual performance overhead. Of course, can't back that up with any documentation, just my personal opinion.

Comment: Thanks i will check my design flow to find some trouble. Actually i can't convert my app to file system locig, so i'm forced to save images on db...